# Can't figure out this old webkit CSS3 gradient

Tags: css, webkit, gradient

So, I found this neat code which had some gradient effects with CSS3, but only with the old webkit syntax.

I'm trying to get it to work in the other browsers, but I can't figure out how to convert it to the right syntaxes.

This is the code:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
      color-stop(0%,rgba(221,221,221,1)),
      color-stop(50%,rgba(221,221,221,0.01)),
      color-stop(100%,rgba(221,221,221,1))
);
```

And:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
    color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,.1)),
    color-stop(85%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01)),
    color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,.35))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one would be:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(left top,
                                  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,
                                  rgba(221,221,221,0.01) 50%,
                                  rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%
                                  );
```

I leave the second one as an exercise to you;) For a little help:

[The spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients)

[Gradient Tool](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)